# Is there a Mac/PC variant of Application.GetOpenFilename?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Is there a universal OS variant of this? I am looking to have this code work on a Mac and PC, but this seems only to work on a PC.

```
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (.csv),.csv", , "Please selec text file...")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in MAC (Excel 2011) As well. See screen shot

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**
Upon discussion in chat as I suspected the error was not with `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` but something else. In this case it was `Application.GetOpenFilename`

Now `Application.GetOpenFilename` definitely gives a problem in Mac. I would recommend seeing this thread which also addresses your problem.

[Error when closing an opened workbook in VBA Userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612502/error-when-closing-an-opened-workbook-in-vba-userform)

Comment: What error message did you get? Is Excel 2011 updated with the latest service pack (though I doubt that will be the reason)?

Comment: It is updated, and the error is `Run-time error '1004': Method: 'GetSaveAsFilename' of object '_Application' failed` in the line `NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xlsx", fileFilter:=NewFileType)`

Comment: Ok When does the error occur? The moment that line is `executed`? or when you press `cancel` or when you press `save`? Can you show us the code for the complete sub?

Comment: or better still can you upload your file? I can test it in MAC

Comment: http://www.kaboomlabs.com/excel/OORv14.xlsm  This will only be up for a few minutes... since it is a lot of what I've worked on since I've come here.  That being said click on Jobs List tab, and click on Update PO Tracking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16249/discussion-between-matt-ridge-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Ok, added in the script you linked to in chat, and I'm getting an error, after the script opens the browser screen, and I select the file in question, and then once selected I open it and I get this error. http://www.kaboomlabs.com/excel/img/error.jpg the error highlights `Set opened_workbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)` here.

Comment: Then it is a different thing altogether :) At least your `Application.GetOpenFilename` lcode is now working and not giving you any error. :) I will check your file in sometime.

Comment: Thanks, just edited prior response with the error highlighted.

Comment: What value do you get for `filename` when you debug it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16253/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-matt-ridge)

Answer (score 5):

I find that I am able to use `Application.GetSaveAsFileName` on both PC and Mac without issue.

```
FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:=filterString, InitialFileName:=myInitialFileName)
```

However I also found that `Application.GetOpenFilename` does not work on the Mac, so I did some googling and came up with this function as a workaround on the Mac:

```
#If Mac Then
    tempfnameList = Select_File_Or_Files_Mac()
#Else
    tempfnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:=filterString, Title:="Select File(s) to Open", MultiSelect:=True)
#End If
```

Here is the implementation of `Select_File_Or_Files_Mac`:

```
Function Select_File_Or_Files_Mac() As String()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyScript As String
    Dim MyFiles As String
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim FName As String
    Dim mybook As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    MyPath = MacScript("return (path to documents folder) as String")
    'Or use MyPath = "Macintosh HD:Users:Ron:Desktop:TestFolder:"

    ' In the following statement, change true to false in the line "multiple
    ' selections allowed true" if you do not want to be able to select more
    ' than one file. Additionally, if you want to filter for multiple files, change
    ' {""com.microsoft.Excel.xls""} to
    ' {""com.microsoft.excel.xls"",""public.comma-separated-values-text""}
    ' if you want to filter on xls and csv files, for example.
    MyScript = _
    "set applescript's text item delimiters to "","" " & vbNewLine & _
               "set theFiles to (choose file of type " & _
             " {""public.comma-separated-values-text""} " & _
               "with prompt ""Please select a file or files"" default location alias """ & _
               MyPath & """ multiple selections allowed true) as string" & vbNewLine & _
               "set applescript's text item delimiters to """" " & vbNewLine & _
               "return theFiles"

    MyFiles = MacScript(MyScript)
    Dim returnList() As String
    On Error GoTo 0

    If MyFiles <> "" Then
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .EnableEvents = False
        End With

        'MsgBox MyFiles
        MySplit = Split(MyFiles, ",")
        ReDim returnList(LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit))
        For N = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)

            returnList(N) = MySplit(N)

        Next N
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        Select_File_Or_Files_Mac = returnList
    Else
        ReDim returnList(0 To 0)
        returnList(0) = "False"
        Select_File_Or_Files_Mac = returnList
    End If
End Function
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: In 2021, on new versions of Excel / new macbook, I still have to do this, but this was the ONLY solution that worked! To be VBA noobies, simply create a new module and copy the above function to it. Then modify your other code arrodingly with the IF Then lines of code but without the #

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution on MSDN -
[Programmatically Selecting Files in Excel for Windows and Excel for the Mac](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh710200%28v=office.14%29.aspx)