# VBA macro working on Excel 2016 for Windows but not for mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I've got a macro on Excel 2016 which works great to create PDF.
But this macro only works for Excel 2016 for Windows.
I try it on Excel 2016 (last version) for Mac and it doesn't work.

Here is my macro

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim Chemin As String
Dim texte As String

Chemin = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/"
texte = Range("C3")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=Chemin & texte & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False

Cells(1, 3).Value = Cells(1, 3).Value + 1

End Sub
```

I made lots of searches and it seems that the "ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF" doesn't work on the last Excel version for Mac. 
But I can't find any other way.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507253/excel-vba-code-to-work-on-mac-create-pdf-function

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

I wrote code in English in Excel 2016 (on an HP computer with Windows installed), then I tried to execute the same Excel file on a Mac that was installed in French. I noticed that the issue is the language.

For example, the problem code:

```
Private Sub 
  Cancelbutton_Click()... 
End Sub
```

For it to execute it needs to be:

```
Private Sub 
  Cancelbutton_Cliquer(...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create folders or create files on the MAC via Excel, you need to use `Scripting.FileSystemObject`:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```