# VBA windows to mac

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I made a code on my Windows PC, have multiple macro's/VBA's but made the  file for somebody with an Mac.

not sure where to start with adjusting code, but has anyone a clue how the following problems are caused, this will help me with finding a solution.. I probably used windows specific components..

if somebody can push me in the right direction, it would be great.. Have found a few topics:
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-12976.html

and this one probably has the solution for my PDF problem:
[Excel VBA code to work on Mac, Create PDF Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507253/excel-vba-code-to-work-on-mac-create-pdf-function)

Problem 1: colomnwidth doesn't work:

```
End With
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 26
Columns("C:H").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 4.5
Columns("J:L").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 11.5
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 16.25
Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 11.5
Columns("J:L").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 10.25
Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Button to make PDF gives "Could not Create PDF"

```
Sub SaveConcept()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Range("N8:N9").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5287936
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

Set ws = ActiveSheet

strFile = Range("J15") _
            & Format(Now(), " dd-mm-yyyy") _
            & Format(" Concept") _
            & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
  ActiveSheet.Range("L1", _
   ActiveSheet.Range("L1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlToLeft).End(xlToLeft).End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown)).ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End If
exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: Which version of Mac Office?

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be an issue with the first part<sup>+</sup> as it's nothing specific to windows, for the second part - you're using "\" as the path separator for the PDF file, on a Mac this is typically ":"

To make the code compatible for both, use the application value instead:

```
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & strFile
```

---

<sup>+</sup>*note: [this was OP code at time of answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37315425/1)*

Comment: Thanks, this probably works.. How can I learn this? is there some kind of 'conversion page'? I replaced the first code above with a piece where there is a error as well.. any idea whats wrong? or how I can figure it out myself?

Comment: You can't use `SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False` on 2011. Those parameters don't exist.

Comment: ah, so that's the issue... is there a work around except from buying the 2016 version?

Comment: @Rory; i tried your solution but i think i made a mistake adding it. had the chance to test it on a Mac but it seems that it doesnt work... I added my new code above..